# Using Compass Twitter FrameWork

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have been trying to learn Ruby On Rails and just found Compass Twitter Bootstrap  which seems to be a good tool , I have been looking at the following git hub https://github.com/vwall/compass-twitter-bootstrap and they do have instructions on how to install Compass Twitter Bootstrap, there are all the folders which would exists in a Ruby on Rails application. But I am not sure how to use this in tuby on rails? Should I just download folders on my local system and create my html pages? Also show the demo application below where Compass Twitter Framework has been used but not sure if I can just download the folders and how can i use it in the Ruby On Rails 3.2. Thanks for your help.

https://github.com/vwall/Compass-Twitter-Bootstrap-Demo-App

Demo Applicatin:http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples/fluid.html#

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of "gems"?  Are you following the instructions on the readme associated with this project?  If the answers to either of these questions is "no", then you should be asking a very different question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this with this gem: https://github.com/vwall/compass-twitter-bootstrap

This page gives instructions on how to use it in a Rails app.